# Calculating the odds

Tags: probability

I have a board with 90 squares on it.

Under 52 of those squares are prizes.  The other 38 are blanks.

I get 6 picks per day.

What are the odds of me, on the first day, of getting 6 blanks?

After 3 days, what are the odds of me having 12 blanks and 6 prize tokens?

Not a math homework question.  On a website I visit, they give away prizes daily and I really did get 6 blanks on my first day and after 3 days, I have 12 blanks and 6 prize tokens.  I was just wondering what the chances of these events happening are, particularly the first one.  Thanks.

Edited to change the correct number of blanks to 38.

Comment: Assuming drawing without replacement, getting $k=6$ blanks (*objects of type A*) out of $n=6$ pulls from a population of which $K=48$ are of type $A$ and $52$ are of type $B$ (*and so $N=52+48=100$ overall, not $90$*) the **probability** (*not to be confused with odds*) of this occurring is $\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}=\dfrac{\binom{48}{6}\binom{52}{0}}{\binom{100}{6}}$ following from basic understanding of counting principles or from the HyperGeometric Distribution.

Comment: With regards to multiple days, the rules are unclear whether you get an entirely new grid to work from or if you continue from the old.  In either event, you can continue with hypergeometric distribution as before.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant 38 blanks instead of 48, then probability P of only getting blank on the first day looks like this:
$$P=(38÷90)×(37÷89)×(36÷88)×(35÷87)×(34÷86)×(33÷85)$$
$$P=0.0044340124$$

Every event has one fewer square to look at and one fewer blank to possibly get. This is of course assuming it's entirely random.

Comment: It's a gambling website so I'd be highly surprised if it was completely random but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We're sampling without replacement, so our trials are dependent and we can't use the binomial distribution. Instead, assuming every tile is equally likely to be chosen, we can just count the number of ways that you could have picked $6$ tiles and then find how many of those would lead to you having $6$ blanks.

I won't get too much into the details but we can use the combination counting function to find how many ways we can make these selections. We end up with $\binom{90}{6}$ ways to pick $6$ tiles and $\binom{38}{6}$ ways to pick only blanks, giving us a probability of $$\frac{\binom{38}{6}}{\binom{90}{6}} = 0.00443$$
which matches Lord Ratte's answer.

The second problem is a lot more complicated because assuming you get a new board each day, now we have to consider the different ways you can arrive at $6$ out of $18$ prizes from $3$ repetitions of this process. Let's say you get $a$ prizes on the first day, $b$ prizes on the second, and $6 - a - b$ on the third, where $a, b \geq 0, a + b \leq 6.$ Assuming the repetitions of this process are independent, we can find the probability for these events on each day and then multiply all of the probabilities together to get the probability of the combined event. Then, to get the total probability for $6$ out of $18$ we can use the law of total probability and add the probabilities for each choice of $a$ and $b$ together.

For any given day with $a$ prizes for $6$ choices from $90$ squares, we get a probability of $\frac{\binom{52}{a}\binom{38}{6-a}}{\binom{90}{6}},$ where $\binom{52}{a}$ represents the ways to choose $a$ prizes, $\binom{38}{6-a}$ represents the ways to choose $6-a$ blanks, and $\binom{90}{6}$ chooses the total number of possible choices. We can use this same argument for the second and third days to arrive at a probability of

$$\frac1{\binom{90}{6}^3}\sum_{a = 0}^6 \sum_{b = 0}^{6 - a} \binom{52}{a}\binom{38}{6-a}\binom{52}{b}\binom{38}{6-b}\binom{52}{6-a-b}\binom{38}{a+b} = 0.0200$$

If you'd like you can also calculate the probability of you getting $6$ *or fewer* prizes from playing three times by replacing all of the $6$'s with $k$'s and summing that from $k = 0$ to $6.$ I calculated that sum as $0.0600.$ This is probably a more relevant value for measuring how lucky/unlucky a certain result is.